# Thinking about a probability problem in terms of sets.

Tags: probability

Here is the problem that I am working on:

[image]

We have $A_1 \setminus A_4 = A_1 \cap A_4^c = \{(x, y) : x \leq 2, y \leq 4\}\cap\{(x, y) : x > 0, y > 1\} = \{(x, y) : 0 < x \leq 2, 1 < y \leq 4\} = A_5$. From here I'm not sure how to conclude anything about about $P(A_5)$ since $A_1$ and $A_4^c$ are not disjoint and we can't just add them.

The solution in the book says the answer is $P(A_5) = 1/4$. I'm assuming that is because $P(A_1) - P(A_2) - P(A_3) + P(A_4) = 1/4$, or some similar adding and subtracting argument.

I am not seeing what exactly or why I should be adding or subtracting though. Could someone clarify this?

Comment: It looks like the solution in your book is not very detailed, and you would like us to clarify it, is it correct?

Comment: Correct, I'll edit that into the OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $P \left( (x, y) \in A_5\right)$

\begin{eqnarray*}
 &=&P( 0 < x \leq 2; 1 < y \leq 4)\\ &=& P(x \leq 2; 1 < y \leq 4) - P(x \leq 0; 1 < y \leq 4) \\
   &=& \left[P(x \leq 2; y \leq 4) - P(x \leq 2; y \leq 1)\right] - \left[P(x \leq 0; y \leq 4) - P(x \leq 0; y \leq 1)\right] \\
   &=& \left[P\left( (x, y) \in A_1\right) - P\left( (x, y) \in A_2\right)\right] - \left[P\left( (x, y) \in A_3\right) -P\left( (x, y) \in A_4\right)\right]  
\end{eqnarray*}

The second and the third equalities are correct because $$P(z \in (B \setminus C)) = P(z \in B) - P(z \in C)$$ The other equalities are just the definition of the $A_\cdot$'s..

Please let me know if anything is unclear.

Comment: Thank you so much, this answer is very clear.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: For every $A\subseteq\mathbb R^2$, consider the function $\mathbf 1_A$ defined on $\mathbb R^2$ by $\mathbf 1_A(x,y)=1$ if $(x,y)$ is in $A$ and $\mathbf 1_A(x,y)=1$ if $(x,y)$ is not in $A$. Then $$\mathbf 1_{A_5}=\mathbf 1_{A_1}-\mathbf 1_{A_2}-\mathbf 1_{A_3}+\mathbf 1_{A_4}.$$